# Sync 2 tables of different databases - MySQL

Tags: mysql, replication, synchronization

I've a table with certain medical information in a database table. I crawl & parse them daily and store it in that table of my local database.

Suppose there were 1500 records initially, today 100 more records are added on my local machine.

Now, I've a server in which I need to push those records (so the database is different). I copied the database yesterday. So, the server database table has 1500 entries now. How can I sync the new 100 entries to the live application?

Please note that I cannot delete old entries from my local machine else it will be crawled again and again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may want to use 'SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE' and 'LOAD DATA INFILE INTO TABLE' commands.

Edit: Elaboration...

Given the table structures:

```
CREATE TABLE my_local_table (
    id int NOT NULL auto_increment PRIMARY KEY,
    data varchar(20),
    created_on datetime);

CREATE TABLE server_table (
    id int NOT NULL auto_increment PRIMARY KEY,
    data varchar(20),
    created_on datetime,
    local_id int);
```

And some bogus data:

```
INSERT INTO my_local_table (data, created_on) VALUES ('test', now()), ('test2', now());
```

You would use the following commands:

```
SELECT id, data, created_on 
    FROM my_local_table
    WHERE created_on >= '2011-08-18'
    INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/t.txt';

-- (and on the server)
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/tmp/t.txt'
    INTO TABLE server_table
    (local_id, data, created_on);
```

To automate the two, you can use a bash script / batch file calling mysql connecting first to the local server using the first statement, then to the remote server executing the second.

```
mysql -e 'SELECT....';
mysql -h remote_server -e 'LOAD DATA...';
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate on the SQL query to be more specific and how can I automate the process?

Comment: Both DB are in the same server..and they already have tbl A1, tbl A2, tbl A3, in DB A .... while tbl B1, tbl B2 , tbl B3 in DB B

Answer (score 0):

You want to set up replication between the server and your local machine -- see the [reference documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication-howto.html) for details.