# would it be reasonable to clone (e.g. db_de) the database and translate it for a second language?

Tags: php, mysql, multilingual

Would that be a good way to add a language to the webpage by cloning the database. Perhaps the database name could change from so that the php connects every time when the language changes to the desired database. I could even store the database into the session.

I have red about different ways that are better than this way. but this seems to be a good way to add a language to a webpage that is already finished and running for a time. What would you suggest for a quick solution? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Cloning the tables instead of the database and appending a locale identifier (eg `_de` after the tablename) is a much better solution.

2) Adding one smallint field (with index) in your tables to indicate the language and rephrasing all your queries to use that field is even better, but may need a little extra work and debugging.

I'd personally go for `1)` as it's much easier than `2)`. Just use a variable which contains the language part of the table name. It can be `_de` for German, or blank for your current default language. Then just append this var in your code to every table that has a translation eg.`my $query = "SELECT * FROM mytable$lang";`

Other ways are better but not as easy to implement.

Databases are huge things and they don't come for free, don't create too many of them.

Comment: yes you are absolutely right. if i would design the database from scratch i would use different ways for sure. but in this situation i have to do this in the shortest time. my thinking was to clone the database and change the main connection that is in the config file. do you mean this at your first suggestion? at the beggining of the connection i could use a session variable for the new PDO('mysql:dbname='.$db_name.';host='.$db_host.'', $db_user, $db_pass); what do you think ?

Comment: @Skeletor I guess that having 2 or 3 databases total would not hurt your performance and disk utilisation too much. I believe that it's not too bad if you do it this way, depending on the load of your website. But you should remember the details. For example, if your users can have accounts and login you'd have to remember that each database may have different user details.

Comment: hmm yes that is right @fobis. actually there is a cms in the database. and it has a user table. is there a way to sync specific tables of two databases. in this way i could just sync them to pass the situation you mentioned. i guess this brings another question.

Comment: @Skeletor I can only think of replication, but it's not that easy to setup and I'm not sure it is appropriate for this situation. Regardless of the complexity of your CMS, I think it's easier to just clone the tables. Maybe sb will know better than me on this subject. Is this useful? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7112257/sync-2-tables-of-different-databases-mysql

Comment: yes this looks a little complicated and i guess i have to do this for every query of for most of them. i think the best for me is to clone the db and separate the admin part. so i can use it common for both langues. thx @foibs for your support.